# Disabling Particular days in Wpf datepicker for all months and years without min and max date range

Tags: c#, wpf

```
`<DatePicker x:Name="dpFrom"  CalendarOpened="dpFrom_CalendarOpened_1"/>
 <CheckBox x:Name="chkSun" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="678,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkMon" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="714,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkWed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="791,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkTue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="752,248,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkThu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="826,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkFri" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="865,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkSat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="897,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>`
```

I have a datepicker and 7 check boxes like(Sun,Mon,...Sat),
If i am checking on any check box(eg:sun,Mon) then that day/days(sun,Mon) has to be disabled in the date picker control for all months.Please help me how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Share the code of your date picker control

Comment: @Lourens I don't have any code for this,All I have is a Date picker and 7 check boxes in design form . I have not written any code  for this because i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Which DatePicker control will you be using? WPF extended toolkit?

Comment: @ZoolWay Yes, WPF extended toolkit.

Comment: @Mayur Dhingra I have shared the code which i have, please check again.

Comment: How about using a event trigger? What I would do is to trigger an event when a checkbox is checked and inside the trigger disable the specific data in the calendar

Comment: @Gino That would work, but can u share the code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are boundaries for the displayed dates in your `DatePicker` (e.g. from 500 days ago to 500 days in the future) then you can handle it via `CheckBox.Checked` and `CheckBox.UnChecked` events.

Here is a sample code:

**Xaml:**

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dpFrom"  />
<CheckBox  Content="Sunday" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" />
<CheckBox  Content="Monday"  Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
<CheckBox  Content="Tuesday"  Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
<CheckBox  Content="Wednesday" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
<CheckBox  Content="Thursday" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
<CheckBox  Content="Friday"  Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
<CheckBox  Content="Saturday" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
```

**Code behind:**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dpFrom.DisplayDateStart = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(500); ;
        dpFrom.DisplayDateEnd = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(500);
    }

    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var chbText = ((CheckBox)sender).Content.ToString();
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
        Enum.TryParse(chbText, out dayOfWeek);

        var minDate = dpFrom.DisplayDateStart ?? DateTime.MinValue;
        var maxDate = dpFrom.DisplayDateEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue;

        for (var d = minDate; d <= maxDate ; d = d.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (d.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)
            {
                dpFrom.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(d));
            }
        }
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var chbText = ((CheckBox)sender).Content.ToString();
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
        Enum.TryParse(chbText, out dayOfWeek);

        var minDate = dpFrom.DisplayDateStart ?? DateTime.MinValue;
        var maxDate = dpFrom.DisplayDateEnd ?? DateTime.MaxValue;

        for (var d = minDate; d <= maxDate ; d = d.AddDays(1))
        {
            if (d.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek)
            {
                dpFrom.BlackoutDates.Remove(dpFrom.BlackoutDates.First(item => item.Start == d ));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Note** that I set the `Content` of each `CheckBox` exactly the same as the members of `DayOfWeek` enum, in order to Add/Remove `BlackoutDates` by `CheckBox.Content`.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but i don't have any boundaries for showing dates. I have to do it for all the months and years.

Comment: Can you do it with out using start date and end date??